# How to update a specific row in database on a button click in dynamically generated table

Tags: android, sqlite

[Android Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xS5zl.jpg)

This is a dynamically generated table and on clicking the accept button only the corresponding row's 'status' field text 'pending' need to be updated to 'accepted'. What should be the code? My query udpates all rows status field from pending to accepted.

```
Adminactivity.java(dynamically generated column code)

 for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
 {
        TextView tv1 = new TextView(AdminActivity.this);
        tv1.setText("Acccept");
        tv1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                                                    tv1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
 tv1.setTextSize(12);
                           tv1.setPadding(5, 0, 0, 0);
                            // tv1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                            tv1.isClickable();
                            tv1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                            tv1.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
                            row1.addView(tv1);


                       tv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                           @Override
                           public void onClick(View v) {

                               // Integer iid=dbHelper.getid();
                               dbHelper.accept("accept", "pending",k);
                               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Accepted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                               //   notify();
                           }
                       });
                    }
```

DBhelper.java
 public Cursor accept  (String accept,String pending)
    {

```
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();

           ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    String query="UPDATE register6 SET status='"+accept+"' WHERE status='"+pending+"'";

    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(query, null);
 if(cursor!=null) {

        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
        return cursor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the query is correct and meets your db conditions?

look-->

is `register6` your table?

is `status` your column?

try to look the syntax linked here : [syntax update](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)

Comment: yes.. Ok I got it .. I copied the 'i'th value into a final variable and passed to the function and inside db helper class i set the selection criteria using it.  String query="UPDATE register6 SET status='"+accept+"' WHERE status='"+pending+"' AND id='"+rowid+"'"; Where final variable passed is the rowid

Comment: @SreyaSringa `id` is a string or an int because if it is an integer you don't need to use ' ' where you have `" ...  id="+rowid+" ";`